# Cocos2d v3 & chipmunk collision detection issues

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, collision

First try at Chipmunk.

Not getting collision detection registering is the problem.

My code:

```
@implementation MainPlayScene
{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physics;
    CCNode *MyPhysicsBody;
    CCNode *bottomBody;

}

+ (instancetype)scene
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (instancetype)init
 {
 // Apple recommend assigning self with      supers return value, and handling self not created
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    _physics = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    _physics.debugDraw = YES;
    [self addChild:_physics z:1];

 /// BOTTOM
    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,      [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize.width, 10);
    bottomBody = [CCNode node];
    bottomBody.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithPolylineFromRect:bottomRect     cornerRadius:0];
    bottomBody.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[@"Bottom"];
   bottomBody.physicsBody.type =     CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    [_physics addChild:bottomBody];

  /// MyBody to bounce around
    MyPhysicsBody = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"MyBody-64x64-24.png"];
    MyPhysicsBody.position = ccp((self.contentSize.width/2),(self.contentSize.height/2));
    MyPhysicsBody = [CCNode node];
    MyPhysicsBody.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero,  MyPhysicsBody.contentSize.height,MyPhysicsBody.contentSize.width} cornerRadius:0];
      MyPhysicsBody.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[@"MyBody"];
    [_physics addChild:MyPhysicsBody z:150];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
```

Detecting touch events and applying force to physics body to have it bounce up and down onto bottom body

```
 - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    CCLOG(@"Touch Detected");
    [MyPhysicsBody.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 300.f)];
}
```

Now I try to detect a collision on “Bottom” but nothing is being registered even though I see debug lines of 2 objects touch.

```
/// try onCollisionEnter first ... nothing 
-(void)onCollisionEnter:(CCNode *)entity collisionPair:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair
{
    if ([entity.physicsBody.collisionCategories  isEqual: @"Bottom"]) {
        CCLOG(@"Hit bottomBody");
    }

}

/// try ccPhysicsCollisionBegin pair ... nothing
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair MyBody:(CCNode *) MyBody Botton:(CCNode *)Bottom
{
     CCLOG(@"Hit bottomBody");
     return TRUE;
}
```

Obviously I’m missing something critical here …

Any help is VERY appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am finding it difficult to see the relevant code with all the things you posted.

I will give you an example of 2 `CCSprite` objects collision detection. One is called `_arrow`and the other one is `_obstacle`.

First step is to define the collision types like so :

```
_arrow.physicsBody.collisionType = @"arrow";
_obstacle.physicsBody.collisionType = @"obstacle";
```

Second step is to define the callback

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair arrow:(CCNode *)arrow obstacle:(CCNode *)obstacle
{
    // Do some cool stuff
    return TRUE;
}
```

Notice the naming, arrow and obstacle according to the **collision type** of theses sprites.

And third, the one that you forgot to do is set the **delegate** so you actually get these methods called on your **physicsNode** object

```
_physics.collisionDelegate = self;
```

And `self` (which is typically just your scene) should implement the `CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I didn't have the  [code] _physics.collisionDelegate = self; [/code] which was the problem. Thank for the help :)

Comment: I actually have `_physics.collisionDelegate = self;` but, when I put a breakpoint on `ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:typeA:typeB:`, it just never gets called.  What I want to do is ignore certain types, so I can `return NO;`, but I'm just never getting that far.  :(

Comment: Oh wow, I *JUST* figured it out.  I'll enter my additional hint in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Tibor has the correct answer, but there's an important clue that I was missing which was driving me crazy.  From the comments in `CCPhysicsNode.h` section on  the `CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate`:

```
The final two parameter names (typeA/typeB) should be replaced
with names used with CCPhysicsBody.collisionType or
CCPhysicsShape.collisionType.
If both final parameter names are "default" then the collision
method is called when a more specific method isn't found.
```

So I was incorrectly trying to implement something like this:

```
-(BOOL) ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    // Compare if we're ignored collisions
    if (([nodeA.physicsBody.collisionType isEqualToString: @"foo"])
    ||  ([nodeB.physicsBody.collisionType isEqualToString: @"foo"]) )
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But that's **WRONG!!!**  The correct thing I wanted to implement was this:

```
-(BOOL) ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair foo:(CCNode *)nodeA foo:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    return NO;
}
```

Note how the ignored collision type is ***part of the method signature***.

Whew!

**EDIT:**

For completeness, don't forget to do:

```
_physics.collisionDelegate = self;
```

Comment: perfect man... you are so clear. I am such an idiot not to read that important comment.

Comment: There's no idiocy involved -- it's very well hidden, and not a very standard way to do things.  A good puzzler!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting collision categories which along with collisions mask allow you to discard certain collisions. The collision type property is what works with the delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I just tried:
    ... /// redefine collisionType not collisionCategory
    headPhysicsBody.physicsBody.collisionType = @"Head";
    bottomBody.physicsBody.collisionType = @"Bottom";
    ...

    -(void)onCollisionEnter:(CCNode *)entity collisionPair:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair
    {
     CCLOG(@"onCollisionEnter");
     if ([entity.physicsBody.collisionType  isEqual: @"Bottom"]) {
        CCLOG(@"Hit bottomBody");
     }   
    }

And still no detecting a collision. 

I put a CCLog just to see if onCollisionEnter is ever being called and it's not. Any ideas?